# Is a weakly contractible connected metric space, uniquely geodesic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, homotopy-theory, geodesic

A topological space is [weakly contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible) if all the [homotopy groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) are trivial.
It's [connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) if it's not the union of two disjoint nonempty open sets.
A [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)  $(X,d)$ is *uniquely geodesic* if two points $x,y \in X$ are connected by a unique path of minimal length, precisely $d(x,y)$.

> **Question** : Is a weakly contractible connected metric space,  uniquely geodesic ?

In the case of a negative answer :
- What are the classical counter-examples ?
- Are there natural additive conditions for having an affirmative answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *topological* property of being weakly contractible does not say much about the *metric*.

The real line with the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|^{1/2}$ is not geodesic; in fact it has no paths of finite length.

[Pac-Man shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPacman-cutscene.png) with the restriction metric from $\mathbb R^2$ gives another example: rectifiably connected, but not geodesic.

Yet another example: a non-strictly convex normed space such as $\ell_1$ or $\ell_\infty$. These are geodesic, but not uniquely geodesic.

A sufficient condition for being uniquely geodesic is the triangle comparison property dubbed [$\mathrm{CAT}(0)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT%28k%29_space).

Comment: I see, thank you very much ! The CAT(0) condition is not necessary, isn't it ? Do you have an example of uniquely geodesic non-CAT(0) contractible space ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Yes, for example $\ell_p$ for $1<p<\infty$, $p\ne 2$, does not satisfy any curvature bounds, but is uniquely geodesic. The condition of being uniquely geodesic is so simple itself that I would not expect to have something related to it that's easier to verify that the condition itself.